# Possible proxy issue with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Whenever I try to add the following endpoint, "http://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx", during the Managed API setup process and press the Test button I get an error on the server. ERROR - APIProviderHostObject Error occurred while connecting to backend : "stackOverflow preventing me from showing this link", reason: Connect to ws.cdyne.com:80 timed out

When I try this exact same process on a machine outside of our proxy it works fine.  I have gone into the axis2.xml file and added proxy information and even went as far as installing cntlm and setting the proxy to localhost - same error.

I can browse to the above link just fine on this machine.

My environment is Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you talk about clicking the Test button when providing Backend Endpoint in API publisher.

The way that Test button works at the moment (as far as I understand) is that it invokes HTTP HEAD method on the endpoint provided (because according to [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), "*This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.*")

Then it checks response. If response is valid or 405 (method not allowed), then the URL is marked as Valid.

Thus sometimes, if backend is not properly following RFC, you might get otherwise working URLs declared as Invalid during the test because of that improper HEAD response evaluation. Obviously, this is just a check for your convenience and you can ignore the check if you know the endpoint works for the methods and resources you need it to work.

So my advice would be to try ignoring the Test and just finishing setting up and publishing the API.

P.S. I am checking it on [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) but behavior is identical to downloadable API Manager.